# DevExpress XtraReport: boolean filter

Tags: c#, filter, boolean, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm working with devexpress and xtrareport tool.

I have done a filter with a boolean paramenter, defined in this way:

```
this.FilterString = "[ABILITATO] = ?abilitatoParam";
```

it works but... if I want to see records with ABILITATO set to true, I click on True and the same fo False. But if I want to see all the record, without filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done with a string filter.

I use the event ParametersRequestSubmit. Then I check the parameters and I set the value I want:

```
if (e.ParametersInformation[0].Parameter.Value.ToString() == Application.Current.FindResource("Abilitati").ToString())
    e.ParametersInformation[0].Parameter.Value = "True";
else if (e.ParametersInformation[0].Parameter.Value.ToString() == Application.Current.FindResource("Disabilitati").ToString())
    e.ParametersInformation[0].Parameter.Value = "False";
else if (e.ParametersInformation[0].Parameter.Value.ToString() == Application.Current.FindResource("Tutti").ToString())
     e.ParametersInformation[0].Parameter.Value = string.Empty;
```

and this is the filter string:

```
"Contains([ABILITATO], ?abilitatoP)"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's possible with `Iff` condition in `filterstring`. First you must create a calculated field and set `Iff` condition with your set of filter.
Put calculated field as main field.